# Testing controllers using IoC

Tags: tdd

Im started to learn TDD just now. And i have some troubles with testing my controllers. So, i will try to explain.
I have a controller:

```
public AccountController(IStoreService storeService)
    {
        _storeService = storeService;
    }

public virtual ActionResult RenderBalance()
    {
        var model = _storeService.GetStorePageBalanceModel();
        return PartialView("MyControl", model);
    }
```

Here i want to test my RenderBalance action:

```
        public class when_balance_renders
    {
        private static Mock<IStoreService> storeService = new Mock<IStoreService>();
        private static AccountController controller;
        private static ActionResult result; 

        private Establish context = () =>
                                        {
                                           controller = new AccountController(storeService.Object);
                                           result = controller.RenderBalance();
                                        };

        private It should_be_not_null_result = () => { result.ShouldNotBeNull(); };
    }
```

But this code doesn't work. I have this error on debug mode:
*Could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.*

How may i fix it? And can you give me some recommendations about testing controllers.
Thanks, Nogin Anton.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just starting out with TDD, try a simpler approach like classical TDD as pointed out here http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html

Also if you have this error Could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

There is something very basic setup wrong.  Remove lines of code until you can at least compile, then move forward from there.